# Binding data to html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html template and a json object which I am trying to bind to this template.

```js
var template="<li class=\"ui-menu-item\">\r\n\t<div class=\"container\">\r\n\t\t
              <div class=\"content\">\r\n\t\t\t<img src=\"\" alt=\"\" data-field=\"field2\">
              \r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t<p data-field=\"field1\"></p>\r\n\t\t<p> 
              <span data-field=\"field3\"></span><span data-field=\"field4\"></span> 
              </p>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</li>";

var source=[{
                field1: "value1",
                field2: "value2",
                field3: "value3",
                field4: "value4",
                extrafieldn: "valuen"
           }];
```

I don't want to use a binding library. Is there some way to iterate over the `data-field` in the template and read it from the source to finally fill the relevant field in the template. 
For example, find that field2 is required from the data-field for image, read its value from source and insert this value in the src.

Comment: I'd suggest you to try mustache.js, otherwise, you'd just be reinventing. Let me know if you need some help with that for kick start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zg82ftuc/2/)**

You can loop through your object and replace the `key` (field1, field2 ...) in your template by the related `value` to this key (value1, value2 ...) :

```
var template="<li class=\"ui-menu-item\">\r\n\t<div class=\"container\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"content\">\r\n\t\t\t<img src=\"\" alt=\"\" data-field=\"field2\">\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t<p data-field=\"field1\"></p>\r\n\t\t<p> <span data-field=\"field3\"></span><span data-field=\"field4\"></span> </p>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</li>";

var source=[{
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2",
    field3: "value3",
    field4: "value4",
    extrafieldn: "valuen"
}];

$.each(source[0] , function(key, val){
    template = template.split('{'+key+'}').join(val);
});
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This replaces the value of `data-field` once. I made slight changes in my template to make it work (by doing away with data-fields and using a structure like `<img src="{field1}" />` and `template.replace('{'+key+'}',val)`
However, it replaces the field only once. So, if there are multiple fields in the template that want the same data, they don't get replaced.

Comment: You're welcome and good job, to replace all occurence try to use `template = template.split('{'+key+'}').join(val);` instead, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your `data-field` for each array element in `source`

```js
var template = "<li class=\"ui-menu-item\">\r\n\t<div class=\"container\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"content\">\r\n\t\t\t<img src=\"\" alt=\"\" data-field=\"field2\">\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t<p data-field=\"field1\"></p>\r\n\t\t<p> <span data-field=\"field3\"></span><span data-field=\"field4\"></span> </p>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</li>";

var source=[{
              field1: "value1",
              field2: "value2",
              field3: "value3",
              field4: "value4",
              extrafieldn: "valuen"
              }];


data = source[0]

for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // this will check if key is owned by data object and not by any of it's ancestors
        //document.write(key+': '+data[key]); // this will show each key with it's value
        template = template.replace(key,data[key])
    }
}

console.log(template)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.map()` , `.attr()`

```
template = $(template);

template.find("[data-field]").map(function() {
  var field = $(this).attr("data-field");
  $(this).attr("data-field", source[0][field]);
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zg82ftuc/1/